# How do you include subprocess with py2exe?

Tags: python, subprocess, py2exe

When I package my program into an exe using py2exe and try to run it, it comes back with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raman_utility_v1.0.2.pyw", line 386, in <module>
  File "raman_utility_v1.0.2.pyw", line 132, in __init__
  File "raman_utility_v1.0.2.pyw", line 136, in getHome
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 566, in check_output
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 710, in __init__
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 958, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Currently my setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    options={
        "py2exe" : {"includes" : ["sip","subprocess"]}
    },
    windows=[{
        "script" : "raman_utility_v1.0.2.pyw"
    }]
)
```

And to run the setup.py, I run the following cmd:

```
python setup.py py2exe --includes sip
```

I have tried adding subprocess to the cmd like this:

```
python setup.py py2exe --includes sip,subprocess
```

but all that did was break sip.

I tried just copying the subprocess.pyc file into the dist folder, and that did not work.  The last thing I tried was a suggestion from: [py2exe not including the modules from "includes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395904/py2exe-not-including-the-modules-from-includes) which was to use "packages" instead of "includes" (for subprocess).  That did not change anything.  I also tried adding the line:

```
import subprocess
```

at the beginning of setup.py but that did not change anything either

Am I even on the right track?  Any hints you have would be really helpful!

Comment: I can't answer this question - we got frustrated with all of the hoops we were having to jump through with py2exe - we switched to PyInstaller and have had no problems since

Comment: ok, thanks for the input.  I will definitely check it out!  Whatever it takes to get this software released sooner...