# py2exe generated .exe shows error message on windows systems

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, ocr, py2exe

I have developed a python openCV based OCR system and generated an .exe file using py2exe.
The problem is it shows an error message on several Windows systems.

Error message:

`Exception in Tkinter callback
     Traceback <most recent call last>:
     File "Tkinter.pyc", line 1536, in __call__
     File "gui_tes3.py", line 89, in VerifyDocument
     File "gui_test3.py", line 37, in OCR
     File "pytesseract\pytesseract.pyc", line 94, in run_tesseract
     File "pytesseract\pytesseract.pyc", line 161, in image_to_string
     File "subprocess.pyc", line 710, in __init__
     File "subprocess.pyc", line 958, in _execute_child
     WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated....... 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: How exactly did you create the .exe and on what kind of system?

Comment: I have created .exe file using py2exe module of python on windows 7 operating system..... Python version used was 2.7

Comment: Since my system is of x64 bit but i have developed the program on x86 platform.

Comment: do you have all files and folders created by py2exe?

Comment: Something obviously is missing. Is this message all you get?

Comment: @mitiku yes i have

Comment: @rocksteady yes on every system..... I am getting this error only

Comment: pytesseract probably needs *tesseract.exe* in order to work, i.e. you should install tesseract and/or make sure that it is located in a directory that is a part of search PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not an option, but py2exe is not the only tool on the market.

What about using PyInstaller. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237678/how-do-you-include-subprocess-with-py2exe) there is also no answer given, but it is mentioned that after switching to PyInstaller everything worked perfectly well.
Just give it a try.